# How to process tableView's scrollView event in a encapsulated class?

Tags: ios, swift

I tried:

```
tableView.delegate=someClass
```

And then inside someClass, I can use scrollViewWillBeginDragging, scrollViewDidScroll, scrollViewDidEndDragging method to handle scroll event.

BUT! the someClass also take my tableView's [viewForHeaderInSection], [didSelectRowAt] method, and these method can not handle in someClass!

I also tried addObserver inside someClass:

```
tableView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentOffset", options: .new, context: nil)
```

to observer the tableView's scroll position, but "scrollViewDidEndDragging" and "scrollViewWillBeginDragging" event can never be observed!

Comment: This is a very abstract question. Add some more detail explaining / showing what you're really trying to do. What you may need is to handle the scroll events in your tableView controller and "pass them on" to `someClass`.

Comment: I want to handle all tableView's scrolling relate event in isolated class, so I can make this reusable to other viewcontroller, not just put the code on each viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

`UITableViewDelegate` inherits from `UIScrollViewDelegate`.

So when you conform to `UITableViewDelegate`, you get the delgate callbacks for both of these.

Example -

```
class MyViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myTableView.delegate = self
    }
    
    
    // MARK: - UITableViewDelegate Methods
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        /// Callback received here
    }
    /// Other methods as needed from UITableViewDelegate protocol
    
    
    // MARK: - UIScrollViewDelegate Methods
    func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        /// Callback received here as well
    }
    /// Other methods as needed from UIScrollViewDelegate protocol
    
}
```

There is no need to add any observers to get these `UIScrollViewDelegate` callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution, to observe the didEndDragging event, add another observer to tableView's panGestureRecognizer

```
tableView.panGestureRecognizer.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "state", options: [.new,.old], context: nil)
tableView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentOffset", options: [.new,.old], context: nil) 

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey: Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    
    if keyPath == "contentOffset" {
        //handle scrollview's content offset changing
    }

    if keyPath == "state"{
        let pan=tableView.panGestureRecognizer
        if pan.state == .began{
            print("pan state is began!")
        }
        else if pan.state == .recognized{                
            print("is scrollViewDidEndDragging")
        }            
    }
}
```